# How to get the prediction values for two response variables from random forest?

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prediction results for two response variable from random forest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41697/prediction-results-for-two-response-variable-from-random-forest)

I use [randomForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html) R package to do regression `rf = randomForest(A + B ~ C + D, data, ..)`. I want to know what are prediction values for A and B, and use `predict(rf)`. The output is an aggregate value instead of two values for A and B. Do you have any suggestion to implement a `predict` function to generate two predictions?